Visual Studio 2022 >> Powershell - How to support "ctrl + click" >> open file in tab
Within VS Code, terminal can open files by ctrl+click on a file path from within the Terminal Output.
Trying to find a way to do this within Visual Studio 2022 for either 'Developer PowerShell' or 'Developer Command Prompt'
This will help greatly with one of my linter tools (eslint) to open files from reported code (terminal output) issues with a single click.
Possibly an options/Args exist to add to the Options >> Environment > Terminal Profiles.  Any ideas?
